# Is diatomaceous earth actually effective against ticks and lice?

Tags: cats, pest-control, ticks

I've heard that diatomaceous earth is a good alternative to mainstream chemicals like Frontline anti bug drops. I'm wondering if there are any studies supporting this claim? I am specifically looking for information about using diatomaceous earth with cats to deter pests like ticks and lice.

Comment: If I recall, it gets into the exoskeleton on the bugs and sort of causes them to slowly leak out.

Comment: no diatomaceous earth will not deter ticks and lice,ticks are aracnids and diatomaceous earth has little to no effect on ticks.diatomaceous earth will kill adult lice but not the lice eggs.diatomaceous earth is a bit like glasspowder and i do not think sprinkling this on your cat is a good idea.